# Dock Panel Dock right and left

Tags: wpf

I know a only little about dock panel, following is the code is used:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True" >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Top" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10" >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
            <TextBlock Height="24" Name="Welcome" Text="Welcome" FontSize="14" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
            <TextBlock Height="24" Name="Welcomee" Text="Welcomee" FontSize="14" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

The result is like this:

```
WelcomeWelcomee
```

However, the code must result in something like this:

```
Welcome                                                              Welcomee
```

So could you please tell me where I misunderstood the concept.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your first StackPanel should not contain the other two stack panels.
It contains the other two.  `DockPanel.Dock="left"` only applies to the immediate children of the DockPanel.

```
   <DockPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Top" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10" >Top
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                <TextBlock Height="24" Name="Welcome" Text="Welcome" FontSize="14" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
               <TextBlock Height="24" Name="Welcomee" Text="Welcomee" FontSize="14" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
```

Comment: Working and thanks for the explanation on concept.  I would remember that Dockpanel only effects its immediate controls.  Thank you.

Comment: @agent-j this ain't working for me, could you take a look at my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39766035/wpf-dock-panel-dock-left-and-dock-right/39767074?noredirect=1#comment66830119_39767074